# Inheritances in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I ran into this example about inheritances on the web, and I am not easy regarding its results. I'm missing something critical.

```
public class A {

int i = 5;

public A() {
    foo();
}

private void foo() {
    System.out.println(i);

}}

public class B extends A {
int i = 6;}

public class C extends B {
int i = 7;

public void foo() {
    System.out.println("C's foo");
    System.out.println(super.i);
}}
```

I'm trying to figure out what's happening by the following command: `C c =  new C();
System.out.println(C.i);`

I know that when we create a new instance of `C` we approach A's and B's constructures, So We reach to `A()` - (question 1) Does `i` (of A) being initialize on the way?
Now we need to call to `foo()`- (question 2)- Does C's `foo()` consider as an override of A's `foo()`? and what if B had a `foo()` of itself? then it was consider as a override and C's `foo()` was operated?

As far as I know, there is no override when it relates to local variables. How come that `System.out.println(c.i)` is 7 and not 5? shouldn't it b the `i` of the highest-father?

EDIT: My question is not about which foo and i will be used when I use c, is about what happens during these two specific commands, cause obviously A's foo was used and not C's.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three `i` variables here are *completely* independent. Which one is used by any statement is determined at *compile-time* - there's no polymorphism involved. So `A.foo()` will always print out the value of the variable declared in `A`.

Note that these aren't *local* variables by the way - they're *instance* variables.

When you print out `c.i` that uses the variable declared in `C` because the compile-time type of `c` is `C`. You can see this if you write:

```
C c = new C();
A a = c;
B b = c;
System.out.println(a.i); // 5 - variable declared in A
System.out.println(b.i); // 6 - variable declared in B
System.out.println(c.i); // 7 - variable declared in C
```

Note that in a well-written program this sort of thing almost never causes a problem, as variables should be private.

Comment: Hi jon. By these two commands the program prints: 5 7.
why does it print 5 first?

Comment: @Nir: The constructor call to `foo()` prints A.i, which is 5.

Comment: why does C's foo() isn't being called? because A's foo() is private?

Comment: @Nir: Yes - C's foo() isn't overriding A's foo. Try putting the `@Override` annotation on, and it will fail. You can't override private methods. If A's foo() were public or protected, it would print 0 because C.i wouldn't be initialized yet...

Comment: (Assuming that it was public) but it prints (super.i) in C's foo(), so shouldn't it print B.i?

Comment: @Nir: Sorry, yes - but B.i will still be 0 too, because B's constructor hasn't executed.

Comment: Thanks.One last thing, what will happen if I'll write C.foo();
Will I get 6 or 0?

Comment: @Nir: `C.foo()` is a static call, so it will fail at compile-time. Rather than ask a fixed question, why don't you just try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

No, you always use the the class member closest to the class you've instantiated.  So, C c = new C(); will use i=7 and C's foo only.  Class B's i is overridden by class C's i, just as A's i has been overridden by B's i.
There's no chaining going on, just overriding.

Answer (score 0):

A, B, and C each have an instance variable called "i".  If you have a C object and execute foo() you will print C's value for "i".

If you had put foo() in B rather than C, oddly you'd still get C's value for "i" if you have a C object, since the "outermost" version of "i" will be used.

Answer (score 0):

About method overriding and visibility:

A.foo() is private. It means it's not visible to its subclasses. If you want B or C to override A.foo(), A.foo() needs to be protected or public. So in your code, B.foo() doesn't exist, because B doesn't know about A.foo().